# In 中国实行独立自主的和平外交政策, why is 实行 correct and 执行 incorrect?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

> 中国**实行**独立自主的和平外交政策。 ✓
> 中国**执行**独立自主的和平外交政策。 ✗
> <sub>杨寄洲 et al.，1700对近义词语用法对比, p.1514 ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeGev.jpg))</sub>

The above example comes from a reference book which describes the differences and similarities between Chinese synonyms.  It lists 政策 as a collocation for both...

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%AE%9E%E8%A1%8C): 实行 (shí​xíng​) to implement / to carry out / to put into practice
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%89%A7%E8%A1%8C): 执行 (zhí​xíng​) to implement / to carry out / to execute / to run

So I don't see why 执行 is considered incorrect in the example above.

**Question**: In the above, why is 实行 correct, and 执行 incorrect?

Comment: 实行 is "operate" or "carry out"; 执行 is "execute", they are quite different from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

实行 - "implement", "carry out", "to put into practice"

执行 - "carry out", "implement", "to execute"

It seems the two have some overlap, however, 实行 is to carry out/implement/**put into practice** the policies settled through discussion and agreed by all policymakers. The act is timeless.

执行 is to carry out/implement/**execute** the order from the superior, or the established policies, the act is usually conducted in a short duration, or within a finite time frame.

Answer (score 2):

实行 has the sense of ***applying***. E.g. apply a policy/law/regulation/etc, as in 实行计划生育. It's ***abstract***.

执行 is more of ***execution*** upon certain rules. It's ***specific***. E.g. 执行死刑.

But there could be some overlaps in usage in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

执行 imply "to enforce an existing rule on objects"

独立自主的和平外交政策 is the government's own goal, which cannot be enforced on any object.

- 实行 means "to implement/ to establish" but 执行 doesn't e.g. 实行反歧視法 means to implement (establish) the anti-discrimination law, while 执行反歧視法 means to execute (enforce) the anti-discrimination law (to force someone to comply)
- 执行 means "to execute" but 实行 doesn't e.g. 执行家法 cannot be changed to 实行家法